# Connecting OS X to an IPSec VPN

Tags: vpn, mac-osx

The company I work for provide VPN access using the FortiClient for Windows.  This is great for people running Windows but I also wish the connect using OS X.

As far as I can tell the VPN connection is made using IPSec for which OS X can create a connection.  Should it be possible or is FortiClient using something proprietary?

If it is possible what will I need to set up the connection on OS X?  For Windows our IT department provide a configuration file but this is specific for FortiClient.

Comment: You can download FortiClient for Mac from [forticlient.com](http://www.forticlient.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There are two other great IPsec VPN Clients:

- IPSecuritas (Free): http://www.lobotomo.com/products/IPSecuritas/
- Shimo (Paid): http://www.chungwasoft.com/Shimo/

I currently use IPSecuritas to connect to many standard IPsec VPNs.

Answer (score 0):

For IPSec, the built-in OS X client can do both L2TP and Cisco VPNs.  If one of these basic systems is used then the built in client should work with the right settings.

In the past (when OS X 10.4 was the latest version), I've used a FortiClient VPN client with OS X.  If they are using a proprietary IPSec implementation, they should still supply the OS X client to companies that are using their system.

I recommend talking to your company's IT folks for either config options or the client software.

Comment: Well, OS X uses racoon behind the scenes, so you can use the following trick to setup any IPsec configuration you desire even if it's not supported by GUI: add "include "/etc/racoon/remote/*.conf" ;" to /etc/racoon/racoon.conf just before the last include (which is "include "/var/run/racoon/*.conf" ;").  Then configure the VPN using GUI as much as you could and start the connection, while it tries to connect, grab the file in /var/run/racoon/ and save it to /etc/racoon/remote/ - now you can edit it the way you like and it will be used instead the one OS X generates :)

Comment: Using the above approach I never needed to setup any 3rd party IPsec software :)

Comment: @galaxy your comment opened my eyes! Do you per chance know where the UI stores the settings? I need to migrate some 10 (working) vpn connections from one Mac to another.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [VPN Tracker as an IPSec Client for Mac](https://vpntracker.com) for many years. I would highly recommend them.